# Need to not inherit CSS (or reset it) on some text fields in a mobile layout using jQuery.mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, styles, textfield

I love jQuery mobile...it's pretty damn awesome.

However, I have a layout where I don't want to have my text fields use what jquery mobile does to them (round the corners, make them 100% width, add the outline etc etc).

I say etc etc there because I don't know everything else that jQuery mobile does to them, if I did, I'd just create a new CSS class and change all of the properties to what I want...alas, the css file and the js file that come packaged with jQuery mobile is not for the faint of heart....and I'm faint of heart.

I'm nearly 99% certain there there's no way to simply reset-all on a css class, but I'd like to have that last 1% solidified.

If there's not (and I"m pretty sure there's not), can anyone tell me all of the properties I need to reset from jQuery mobile's goings-on for text fields?

The most important one for me right now is the width of the text fields. Even when I explicitly put the width at like 95%, it always fills the parent with 100% width.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done easily, you just need to use a:

```
data-role="none"
```

attribute on wanted field.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LqDke/

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use chromes inspect element tool to see where and what CSS properties are being set on an element (it even gives you the line number in the CSS file).

You can either then edit the jQuery mobile CSS file, or overwrite the CSS properties in another style sheet